# Use of bincount to get average of all duplicate data points in List

Tags: python

I have simplified the data that I have to illustrate the problem.

```
x = [0, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0]    
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
```

I expect to merge the duplicate x values and replace the y values for those duplicate entries with average. For the given data I would expect the result as:

```
x_new = [ 0.   1.5  2.   3.   5. ]    
y_new = [ 10.  25.  40.  55.  70.]
```

I am using numpy module as:

```
import numpy as np

# x = Position Data
# y = Temperature Data
x = [0, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0]

y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]


# Find unique sorted values for x
x_new = np.unique(x)

# Use bincount to get the accumulated summation for each unique x, and
# divide each summation by the respective count of each unique value in x
y_new= np.bincount(x, weights=y)/np.bincount(x)

print x_new
print y_new
```

I, however, see following error in console. I am not sure what is going on with the nan being printed for the new y list.

```
[ 0.   1.5  2.   3.   5. ]
```

> Warning: invalid value encountered in divide

```
[ 10.  25.  40.  55.  nan  70.]
```

I would appreciate if experienced python users can share faster/more efficient ways to achieve same for large data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using native Python with an `OrderedDict`:

#### Code:

```
x = [0, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]

from collections import OrderedDict
values = OrderedDict()
for v1, v2 in zip(x, y):
    values.setdefault(v1, []).append(v2)

new_x = list(values.keys())
new_y = [sum(values[i]) / len(values[i]) for i in values]

print(new_x)
print(new_y)
```

#### Results:

```
[0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0]
[10.0, 25.0, 40.0, 55.0, 70.0]
```

Comment: This was great advice w.r.t to OrderedDict. I am still curious as to why nan was printed in original code with bincount.

Comment: @Stephan, I am new on SO. I have accepted this answer. However, my upvote may not show publicly (# of reputation points). Hope I have followed the forum protocol so far.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's zombie, but in case it helps others.  I suspect the original post didn't work because `np.bincount()` is supposed to be passed a non-negative integer array, and they are passing a floating point array.  I think they need to map the floating point array of `x` to the unique integers, using the return_inverse option in `np.unique()`.

this works with no problem:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([0, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0])
y=np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])
x_new,inv = np.unique(x,return_inverse=True)
y_new = np.bincount(inv,weights=y)/np.bincount(inv)
```

However, another step can be saved by using `np.unique()` properly:

```
x_new,inv,cnt = np.unique(x,return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)
y_new = np.bincount(inv,weights=y)/cnt
```

best of luck.